# Eclipse pull project to develop on another machine

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have a private repository on github.com and I want to pull it down to another development machine so that I can work with it in Eclipse but I am not sure exactly how to do it.

Do I have to create a local repository first or would that be created when the repository is pulled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use git with eclipse, I assume you use eGit.

If you do, you can simply open `File -> Import... -> Git -> Projects from Git -> Clone URI` and from there everything should be clear to you. If it is not, just ask again and I will elaborate.

It will create a local repository for you if you chose so (later in the dialog you can chose something like `import exisiting projects` which is what you want if you already pushed your project to github once).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I'm a little new to GIT.  I've been using TFS for a long time.

Comment: Even though this might have solved your immidiate problem, I strongly recommend you tinker with git a little bit. I also started of using only egit, but you really benefit from reading something about git in general and how it works, even if you don't intend to use the comand line.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get eclipse out of the way. It has nothing to do with pulling/pushing to a remote repository.

The primary purpose of creating a remote repository is code collaboration. You can work on your local and then push to it. Others can pull from the remote and see your changes.

The primary way code collaboration is done in github is using the same model. To create a local branch out of a remote repository, you need to `clone` the repository. Cloning the repository would create a local `master` branch (the default branch) that will track the changes you make to your local repository. The other branch to note is the `origin/master` which tracks the changes you make to the remote repo.

When you want to make changes to the remote, you would need to perform three main steps:

- Clone the existing repository: `git clone https://github.com/johndoe/foo.git`: this will create a local repository with the default master branch. You will work in this branch and when you have made the changes...
- Commit the changes: git commit -m "this is the comment to identify my commit later"
- Push it to the remote: `git push origin master`: `origin` refers to the remote repository; when you have cloned from the remote it is automatically called `origin`

So basically, you just need to clone the remote repository if you already have the remote on github. You don't need to create it separately.

You can import the project you have cloned into eclipse and work with it accordingly, then `commit` and `push` the changes to the remote.

Hope that helps.